# How to recover deleted records in Dynamics CRM 2011 on premises

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

We are setting up our Dynamics CRM 2011 on premises environment and we are interested to know what kind of recovery capabilities exist in Dynamics CRM so we can plan ahead.

We are going to have full weekly backups and differential daily backups but what if someone accidentally deletes records at 9PM and our last differential backup was at 1 PM – data is obviously not going to be in the backup.

Previous versions of Dynamics CRM had soft delete so it was easy to undelete records but this has changed with 2011 version.

Any info would be much appreciated.

Comment: "what if someone accidentally deletes records at 9PM and our last differential backup was at 1 PM – data is obviously not going to be in the backup". I'll tell you what would happen if that occurred: One of you is going to get fired. The guy who did not do backups more often (even though that could get silly when they take longer to run than the time between them), the guy who gave users security roles which allowed them to delete records (even though that is what the business asked for), or the guy who pressed delete and then confirm, then changed his mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you can do to prevent loss of data or recover data if it gets deleted.

Enable auditing for the most important records – even if data is deleted you should be still able to recover using database audit data and SKD. Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/05/23/recover-your-deleted-crm-data-and-recreate-them-using-crm-api.aspx) article for more details.

Review user permissions – see if you can reduce user privileges so that only admins can delete records.

Make more frequent differential database backups - see if you can create differential backups every hour or so.

Use third party tools – check out [ApexSQL Recover](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx) and [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) . These tools claim they can recover deleted data by reading transaction log.

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on what kind of harm you're expecting to experience.

- Carelessness - enabled auditing
- Legal consideration - external web service
- Maliciousness - security roles
- Malfunction - scheduled backups